# CheckBox and TextView in ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Every row of my listview in android have checkbox and textview.
If I click on checkbox, I set up my checkbox checked, but how can I set my checkbox checked if I click on TextView.
Here is my code example.
Thank you on your time.

```
public class PitanjaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Odgovor>{

private ArrayList<Odgovor> odgovorList;
Context context;
private Typeface custom_font;

public PitanjaAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Odgovor> odgovorList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, odgovorList);
    this.context = context;
    this.odgovorList = new ArrayList<Odgovor>();
    this.odgovorList.addAll(odgovorList);
    this.custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Aller.ttf");
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams") 
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.pitanja_entry, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
        holder.code.setTypeface(custom_font);
        holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                Odgovor country = (Odgovor) cb.getTag();
                country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());

            }



        });
        holder.code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Odgovor country = odgovorList.get(position);
    holder.code.setText(country.getContents());
    holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
    holder.name.setTag(country);
    if (odgovorList.get(position).getGreen() != 0 && odgovorList.get(position).getRed() != 0){
        if (country.isSelected() && Integer.parseInt(country.getIs_correct()) == 1){
            holder.code.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tocan_odgovor_drawable);
            holder.name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ikona_box2_tocno);
        } else if (country.isSelected() && Integer.parseInt(country.getIs_correct()) == 0){
            holder.code.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.netocan_odgovor_drawable);
            holder.name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ikona_box2_netocno);
        } else if (!country.isSelected() && Integer.parseInt(country.getIs_correct()) == 0){
            holder.code.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.netocan_odgovor_drawable);
            holder.name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_check);
            holder.name.setEnabled(false);
        } else if (!country.isSelected() && Integer.parseInt(country.getIs_correct()) == 1){
            holder.code.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tocan_odgovor_drawable);
            holder.name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_check);
            holder.name.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }


    return convertView;
}

public void colorized(Odgovor odgovor){
    odgovor.setRed(Color.RED);
    odgovor.setGreen(Color.WHITE);
}

private class ViewHolder{

    public TextView code;
    public CheckBox name;


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put it here becouse i cant comment :(.
Hace you tried with

```
checkbox.setChecked(myboolean)
```

**EDIT**

You should put it out

`public class PitanjaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Odgovor>{
 public ViewHolder holder;`

And then

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null){
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.pitanja_entry, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
    holder.code.setTypeface(custom_font);
    holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            Odgovor country = (Odgovor) cb.getTag();
            country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());

        }
```

This way you give it a value inside getView but you can acces to it from onClick cause it is an outside value. But always make sure to give it a value somewhere before using it or it will be null

To use textview as a buttom you have to use an onclicklistener

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox A = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
            A.setChecked(!A.isChecked());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tryed to implement methond setOnClickListener, and check if the checkbox selected, set checbox selected to false, but then I have to change modifier of ViewHolder to final, and if I change modifier of ViewHolder, I can't instantiet him

Comment: Thank you very much, but why my application set checked always last checkbox. I implement on this way
`holder.code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    
    if (v.isSelected()){
     holder.name.setChecked(true);
    } else {
     holder.name.setChecked(false);
    }
    
   }
  });`

Comment: could you explain it in a different way?, i dont understand the question, what is the problem?

Comment: I want to set checked checkbox when user click on textview. You wrote me code that I posted for checkbox. But how I can implement on click when user click on textview from adapter.

Comment: Im really spoiling you by showing it instead of making you check!, Anyway, you simply have to use an onclicklistener, example in edit. And i must confess that i didnt really look at the code the second time so i didnt notice that you werent actually putting the onclicklistener on a textview but on the checkbox!

Comment: Is it the same way if I want to implement that in adapter, or should I change some things?

Comment: I dont know but i guessit should be the same.